# How do I calculate the fourth vertex of a tetrahedron given the other three?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, tetrahedra

I want to calculate the fourth vertex of a regular tetrahedron. I have the coordinates

> {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])}, {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2
> Sqrt[6]))} and {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))}

Can anybody please help?

Comment: This question is so specific that it's unlikely to help anyone else but you. It would be better to just more generally ask, "How do I calculate the fourth vertex of a tetrahedron given the other three?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the center of face

```
cx = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3 and similar for y,z
```

Get two edge vectors

```
e2x = x2 - x1
e2y = y2 - y1
e2z = z2 - z1
e3x = x3 - x1
e3y = y3 - y1
e3z = z3 - z1
```

Calculate edge len

```
elen = sqrt(e2x*e2x+e2y*e2y+e2z*e2z)
```

Calculate vector product to get normal to this face

```
nx = e2y*e3z - e2z*e3y 
ny = e2z*e3x - e2x*e3z 
nz = e2x*e3y - e2y*e3x
```

Make unit normal

```
nlen = sqrt(nx*nx+ny*ny+nz*nz)
nx = nx / nlen
...
```

Make normal of needed length (tetrahedron height)

```
lnx = nx * sqrt(2/3) * elen
...
```

Add this normal to the face center

```
x4 = cx +/- lnx
y4 = cy +/- lny
z4 = cz +/- lnz
```

`+/-`  signs correspond to two possible positions of the fourth vertex